# Cannot find name '$' in TS file unless referenced in every file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm setting up typescript in Visual Studio 2015. I'm going to be using jquery with the TS files. When I use jquery, VS will underline the '$' and say cannot find name, and will not build successfully. The only way it will build is if I add the reference to jquery typings in each TS file. `/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />`  Is there anyway to use this reference globally instead of adding it to every file?

In Visual Studio Code I dont have this issue.

My directory looks like this
-Scripts
 --ts
   ---typings
   ---main.ts
   tsconfig.json
 --js

My tasks.json file in the root

```
    {
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // Tell the tsc compiler to use the tsconfig.json from the open folder.
    "args": ["-p", "../Scripts/Weblink/ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

---

taskconfig.json in Scripts/ts

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../lib/"
},
"exclude": [
    "typings/*"
]
}
```

Comment: which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Latest version 2.1.4

Comment: Installed with the VS file from typescript, not Node

Comment: try to specify references in the tsconfig.json http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Thanks, it builds successfully now, but VS still underlines the $ with the same error for whatever reason

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.x you should install the typings like this:

`npm install --save @types/jquery`

And then:

`import * as $ from "jquery";`

No need to reference it, TypeScript will handle it automatically.

[More info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: And any plugins should be [added to a typings](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc) file, so the compiler merges these signatures in the known jquery typings interface.

Comment: I'm currently refactoring a code with a lot of `declare const $: any`. Is there any impact on performances, size of the bundle, ... or anything else I can't imagine if replace those by `import * as $ from "jquery"` ?

Answer (score 1):

- **In TypeScript 3 using npm:**

  `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

  And :

  `import "jquery";`

  Alias is not necessary.
- **If you don't use npm:**

  Add a new declaration (jquery.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jquery';`

  And :

  `import "jquery";`

Answer (score 0):

add to your tsconfig.json:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
"lib": [ "es2015", "es2017", "dom" ]
```