# TS2339: Property 'selectpicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I'm using the [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)

I have successfully imported `bootstrap-select` into my project using:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```

within the document `<head>` tag. I want to see how to modify the checkmarks within the multiple select boxes, and figured I would try to use the

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

Method as shown [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/). Whenever I attempt to use that bit of code, I receive an error:

```
TS2339: Property 'selectpicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

I have even tried installing the types definition using

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap-select
```

But the issue still remains. I'm using the Visual Studio SPA template which uses ASP.NET Core template, Vue.js and Webpack.

Answer (score 5):

I recall dealing with this same error. Trying to reproduce the exact same error now, I found that it only shows up after I follow the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168903

My solution, adding this line right below my import statements:

`declare var $: any;`

For context, this has worked fine for me in an my Angular projects. I'm not too familiar with Vue.js but if it's applicable, I think it's a good idea to wrap all the bootstrap-select jQuery code that you need in one unit (in my case I wrap it all in a directive).

It also works without the need to have any typings installed (I don't have @types/jquery or @types/bootstrap-select)